# Flex 4.5 - to long build process

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5, flexbuilder

We are developing an app using flex 4.5. The app runs just fine (no performance issues at all) but it takes us forever to compile and build it. A minor change, like just add a comment or press enter in an mxml file and rebuild takes about 3 minutes. You just cant work that way.

It is a large project with about 1300 files. We also use Parsley as IOC container and a beat of cairngorm navigation. We also use Maven (Flex mojos) but I am talking about a normal eclipse build (Ctrl + B).

We separated some of the code to a different SWC and all of our graphics are stored in a different resource SWF.

Please, Do you have any suggestions?

Regards, Ido

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Summary**

- Turn off auto-build
- Close unrelated projects
- Remap Ctrl+B
- Encapsulate application domains

---

**Turn off auto-build**

First thing to do when you install FlashBuilder is turning off the automatic building "feature". The Flex compiler is waaay to slow to constantly build in the background unless you work on very small projects. It's in menu > Project > Build Automatically.

[image]

**Close unrelated projects**

Any open project eats away memory. Close as many as you can.

**Remap Ctrl+B**

Since you use the Ctrl+B keybinding to launch the build process, you should know that this will actually **build your entire workspace**. Every single project that is open will be built. When you have a lot of dependencies that's gonna take a whole lot of time.

That's why I remap the Ctrl+B combo to just build the project that I'm currently working on. A small donwside is that sometimes you have to go 'manually' build a few projects, but that's largely outweighed by the time gain.

Go to menu > Window > Preferences. Type "key" in the search box. Click the topic "keys" under "general". Now type "build" in the searchbox on the right. Select "Build Automatically" and click the "Unbind Command" button. The ctrl+B binding should disappear. Now select "Build Project", then select the "Binding" input field (lower left) and hit Ctrl+B. Save and you're done.

[image]

**Encapsulate application domains**

I don't have a single project that is bigger than 200 files (usually even less than 100). Since your project consists of 1300 files I assume that it is does not have one monolithic function. So you should be able to slice it up into separate libraries; preferably one for each application domain. This will allow you to compile sizeable bits of the application and has the added benefit of clearly separating some concerns within your application.

Comment: Thank you very much.

But, I understand eclipse should do incremental build, and not build it all from scratch. 

I don't understand what did you mean with "Encapsulate application domains"... I've got a viewstack with different views for different screens. Are you saying that I should build each screen in a seperated SWC? What about modules?

Comment: @user1012646 1) Yes it does incremental build, but it still has to check your 1300 files (+ all other open projects) for any changes. Speed will also depend on the version of FlashBuilder you're using. 2) Modules: don't even think > separate project. As for the other views: if they have discrete functionalities, not too many dependencies between them and are big enough, separate them.

Comment: But having about 10 different projects on the workspace will be difficult to work with. too many SWCs..  Is it a good practice?

Comment: I've had projects with 30 subprojects working without a glitch in FlashBuilder (FDT doens't like it too much though). You can also create "working sets" that group these projects together. For a debug build FB will take care of the dependencies and for production you have your Maven script (which will admittedly become slightly more complex). As for good practice: it separates concerns and you'll notice faster when you create inadvertent dependencies; so yes it's good enough practice.

Comment: If you have not done so already, also disable Design view if you use it (who does?) as from what I understand it's built constantly when it detects changes. This has nothing to do with compilation but should make working with big projects easier.

Answer (score 1):

How to fix slow build time when trying to use the debugger on Flash Builder 4.6 Mobile Apps

I ran into the same problem. Here is how you fix it.

It seem when you build a mobile app with a Server Connection like PHP it writes all of the 
files on the server Directory..

When it come time to compile the app to debug it packages all of the sitting in the server directory. To fix this issue do the following.

- Properties of the project.
- Flex Build Packaging
- for this example Pick Google Android.

Package Contents.
UnSelect anything that does not belong in your project..

After doing this build time when from 30 minutes to under 10 seconds..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, This is how we fixed it:

1. We deleted all the dependencies. Then, we added only the necessary ones. You won't believe how many SWC files were just there and never used.
2. We went through almost every action-script and mxml file, and deleted unnecessary imports (using CTRL+ O on eclipse). This is a lot of work.

   1. We changed the buiders on the project configurations so that only Flex builder remains. There were more builders including Maven. Every builder makes everything slower.

That is it.