# I added class directory via Flex Build Path/Source Path, and now 'building workspace' takes forever

Tags: apache-flex, debugging, flash-builder

I am coming from flash to flashbuilder.

I have a directory, AS3_classes_dir, on my computer that stores all of my classes, including my greensock and papervision packages. In every *flash* app that I make I include that directory in the Source Path, so that I can import whatever I may need. Compiling in flash (using ctrl/enter) takes very little time; only the classes that are specifically imported are compiled.

So today I did that in *flashbuilder*, included AS3_classes_dir via Flex Build Path/Source Path ... but now the compile time are a couple of minutes, even though I am not even importing ANY of the classes from within.

I do not have any other projects open.

Comment: I've had kind of the same issue once, the problem was I was embedding a font that weights several Mo. Do you have anything embedded in your app ?

Comment: hmmm ... I can't say for certain ... none of the classes in AS3_classes_dir that I created would have embedded fonts, as I have always embedded via the flash authoring software.

but there are many other 'libraries' inside AS3_classes_dir, such as papervision3d, greensock, mrdoob, etc ... maybe in one of those classes there is an as3 call to embed a font - but I wouldn't even know how to find that.

Answer (score 1):

The big difference between FlashBuilder and Flash Pro is that the former will load *all* the referenced classes into memory. This is necessary for the code hinting (or intellisense), the automatic imports and the warning/error messages in the IDE to work (and probably some other functionalities that I'm not thinking of right now. If you make FB always load all classes you possibly have, then you're bound to hit a memory wall.

Therefor having one big project with all your classes is simply not a good approach. It also isn't from a maintainability point of view (in a team it would be a nightmare), but that's a different discussion. So I think you should reconsider it. Note that I understand your reluctance to do so, but in the long run it'll pay off to keep your dependencies more organized.

So the first thing you should do, is cutting that huge project into smaller pieces (library projects) that can stand on their own and then link only the dependencies you need into the main project. There are two main ways to link other projects in your main project. In the project properties, go to 'Flex library build path' and select the tab 'Library path'.

- 'Add project...' lets you add another project from your FlashBuilder workspace. Use this option if you're going to make a lot of changes to the dependency project while working on the main project. Note that this is slower than the other option, because the dependency project gets compiled every time the main project is compiled.
- 'Add SWC folder...' and 'Add SWC...' lets you add already compiled libraries. Use this option if the dependency project is relatively stable and will hardly ever change.

I hope this is enough info to get you started organizing your projects. I have also written another answer on a similar question with some performance and organizational tips that might be helpful to you: [Flex 4.5 - to long build process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173625/flex-4-5-to-long-build-process/9174169#9174169)

Comment: I appreciate what you're saying. And I do not disagree with you. However, I would have to effectively 'start all over' with 5-6 years worth of 'as3 class library' development in order to make room for I consider to be an oversight by flashbuilder (I'm a layman though)... 

I suppose that what I would like is for flash builder to realize that it has already 'dealt with' those 1000's of classes which are located in that one folder of folders and are not being used by the project at hand.

To have to re-arrange those, or to start a new library (thus maintaining 2 simultaneously), seems incorrect.

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd Actually, I think it would be a _good_ thing to clean up the mess, but I understand that it may take you more time than you would care for. You might try making that one folder a library project and use that as described in my answer. Perhaps this approach might benefit from FB's incremental build, and if you just put the compiled SWC on the build path (method 2) at least FB won't compile the whole thing every time, but it will still load everything in memory.

Comment: I also noticed you have some third-party libraries in there, so you might want to get started with removing these from the big folder and linking those projects with their compiled SWC's. They'll be the easiest to separate because they have no dependencies among each other.

Comment: but to me it is not a mess, but rather a single repository where all as3 packages are stored, including my own plus 3rd party packages.

'Cleaning up' effectively means 'breaking' dozens upon dozens of old flash projects OR creating 'shells' (such as a swc) for individual packages ... every 'shell' would have to be maintained ... so, suppose I make one change to my_mc_highlighter_class.as, and that that same class is a part of a swc (just for flashbuilder), whenever I make change to that class I would have to update appropriate swc ...

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd It's "a mess" (IMO) because there is no way of knowing what a project's dependencies are exactly. You may have a good overview because you developed the whole thing, but pass it on to another developer and he's at a loss. Does my_mc_highlighter need something from Greensock? I don't know and I can't know unless I read all the related code. If I update Greensock to a newer version, will it break my_mc_highlighter? I don't have a clue. It's just a big pile of classes. And after each project it grows bigger and bigger.

Comment: As for your example: suppose you make a change to my_mc_highlighter. If you have older projects depending on it, first how do you identify which projects are (see previous comment)? And when you have identified them, do you go through all these projects and update them according to the changes in my_mc_highlighter? After 30 projects or so I think you'll really grow tired of doing that. Tools like Maven or Gradle are designed to help you deal with dependencies: they allow you to publish your libraries with versioning to a local or remote repository, where they can be accessed by other projects.

Comment: "a big pile of (packages)" really ... but nevertheless all of your points are valid.

Versioning is done at the point of change within a class: a dated explanation of the change. Then if I open an old project from three years ago, the flash debugger will kindly point me to the breakdown, where there will be a dated explanation waiting for me.

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd I'm starting to get an idea of your workflow now. But to come back at your original issue: if you want FB to play nice, you will have to take _some_ action. As I pointed out in an earlier comment: would it not be possible to create a FB library project in each of the main subfolders? That way you could keep using the 'pile' in your Flash Pro projects and the separate libraries in FB, both with the same source code. Or are the main subfolders just 'com', 'org' and 'net'?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referencing the Library Path:
Make sure you look carefully at the linkage type. In most cases it defaults to 'merge', this is the same with Flash (and how it deals with library.swc's).

You have a couple options

1. Merge everything - this is probably what is taking awhile now.
2. Link as an RSL - meaning you'll load this at runtime

If you feel adventurous you have a lot more options using a build config, like library-path - which merges only used assets.

If you are referencing the Source Path:
This might be an issue with resource linking with eclipse - this is a big tool meant to deal with a lot of different development platforms.

You might try adding a linkage identifier in: Resource > Linked Resources: This will add a pointer directly to the source path in question - assuming this is outside the project scope and default spaces (outside of doucments, and workspace).

Comment: I tried the LinkedResource method, and the linked folder, my_AS3_classes_dir, did show up in the Flashbuilder Package Explorer ... but nevertheless I was NOT able to _import my_class_ which was located within my_AS3_classes_dir.