# Flex 3 Highly productive development

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, development-environment

What are the best approaches to keep a highly productive development environment in Flex. I have problems with Java Heap space. But I suspect my project is so huge that even changing the settings is not helping. I would like to know if using external Libraries can help build time?

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173625/flex-4-5-to-long-build-process/9174169#9174169) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999625/i-added-class-directory-via-flex-build-path-source-path-and-now-building-works/10008319#10008319). Basically, yes split your project up in libraries. Only one project has to be built at a time. You can also assign more memory to the compiler's VM.

Comment: Have you increased the java memory settings for Flash Builder? ( http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F ).    Have you upgraded to the 64-bit version of Flash Builder 4.7?   Can you quantify what type of problems you are having with the Java Heap Space?

Comment: Apparently, using JRockit instead of the standard JVM should also bring a significant improvement: http://mikecann.co.uk/programming/improve-flash-builder-performance-and-compile-times-by-30/

Answer (score 1):

We were using FlashBuilder for years. Our enterprise Flex project was MASSIVE and we reached a critical mass point where we were getting Java Heap Space errors after just 2 compiles.

We tried loads of different java memory settings but it just was not at all stable. We suspected there was a memory leak in the IDE.

We moved over to the 64 Bit version IntelliJ IDEA a couple of years ago and have never looked back. It doesn't improve build times but it is massively more stable and provides loads of extra refactoring tools too.

Splitting into separate libraries will help but you can get into lots of dependency issues which may or may not be resolvable.