# Fast alternative to Flash Builder

Tags: apache-flex, intellij-idea, flash-builder

I have a large application in Flex.
I use Flash Builder to develop it. Flash Builder works good, until I attempt to compile my project.
It takes too much time to check small changes of application interface.

1. Is there faster alternative to Flash Builder? Does InelliJ Idea compile large projects faster?
2. I need to check just one interface panel out of 100, is there any solution that would allow to preview just it (except dividing application into smaller modules)?

Comment: Here's another answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173625/flex-4-5-to-long-build-process/9174169#9174169. My experience is that FB actually compiles faster than the alternatives (or at least it did when I last compared about half a year ago). In the end the bottleneck is the compiler which all of them use and which is incredibly slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FDT and IntelliJ Idea both use the default compiler that is shipped with the SDK for the version of Flex that you use.  I would assume that Flash Builder does the same, but I currently have never used this product.  I know that FDT will compile a relatively large program quickly by only compiling those thing that have changed since the last compile, which is an option for IntelliJ as well.

Before abandoning your current IDE I would check to make sure this is not an option in it as well, I know that if I go from FDT to FlashDevelop or IntelliJ there are several little things that seem to show up in the IDE.  None are really errors, but have to be taken care of prior to a compile to keep things tidy.

If you decide that a change in IDE is a must, I can vouch for any of the above as solid software to work in, with FDT being my current favorite as it has the tools that I use the most.

Comment: I can confirm that FlashBuilder compiles incrementally, through the usage of [fsch](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_01.html)