# Ant Build for flex files takes a lot of time

Tags: apache-flex, ant

Ant build consumes a lot of time and memory for my project. Specially flex and groovy compilation take most of the time. Java build with Aspect wiring happens in 3-5 min but flex and groovy components together takes 120 min.
As I am running Ant from a bat file ANT_OPTS setting is:

```
set ANT_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m
```

System configuration is

```
Ant 1.6
JDK 1.6
Flex SDK 3.6a
RAM 8 GB
```

During the build I get following warning:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: CodeCache is full. Compiler has been disabled.
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: Try increasing the code cache size using -XX
:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
```

I have noticed that flex compiler [mxmlc] builds all the application files irrespective if they are changed or not.
Is there any way I can make it faster?
Currently it takes 120 min to build my application and I am not able to use my machine during that time.

Comment: That must be one mastodon of a project. You probably should slice it up into smaller one's (see last part of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173625/flex-4-5-to-long-build-process/9174169#9174169)

Comment: On my flex builder I am already using all the mentioned tips. But how to deal with it during Ant Build?

Comment: If you cut your project into smaller subprojects, you should not have this memor issue anymore.